# Gas Dryer - Gas Shut Off Valve

Tags: dryer, gas, valve

Replacing our washer/dryer and our old ones are getting picked up tomorrow and the new ones will arrive the day after. We have a gas shut off valve with the dryer but I'm wondering if that is something I can rely on to keep gas completely cut off over a 24 hour period. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Gas shutoff valves are very reliable. If it were to leak, you'd smell the gas. You can always get a plug or a cap and seal the pipe after the valve but I don't think it's necessary.

Who will disconnect the old appliances and reconnect the new ones? Many gas companies will reconnect for free and will test the connections for any leaks. If you paid the appliance store for installation, they should also check for leaks after reconnecting.

Comment: If you leave the valve off for longer term than just a few days then capping is required even after a shut valve.